# Count the number of duplicates in arrays excluing the repeated element in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that copy the common elements from the arrays to the destination[k] and count the number of duplicates. However when I compile my program it counts the repeated elements too, don't know how to fix it
My function compiles but it includes the repeated elements, e.g if the arrays are {1, 1, 1} and {1, 1, 1}, my code will return 3, however it should be 1

I tried ending the program by putting break after k++

```
int remove_duplicates(int length, int source[length], int destination[length]){

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int k = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < length; j++){
      if (source[i] == source[j]){
        destination[k] = source[i];
        k++;
        break;       
      }
    }
  }
  return k;
}
```

I would like to know how to count the number of duplicates excluding the repeated elements

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Your function just copies `source` to `destination`

Comment: but it is returning k at the end, which is the number of elements in destination array

Comment: Explain what you want to happen, your question isn't clear

Comment: Did you try starting j from i+1? And still, that will only test once among each other preventing self comparison.

Comment: To count the number of duplicates, which I have copied to destination array. My function compiles but it includes the repeated elements, e.g if the arrays are {1, 1, 1} and {1, 1, 1}, my code will return 3, however it should be 1

Comment: I tried starting j from i+1 and it still does not work tho

Comment: Hint: sort the list first.  Pseudo code: `destination[] = sort(src[])`

Comment: could you please show exactly how could I do it?